# Two step media creation form?

Tags: 8, media

It would seem very logical to pick the media source first, and then have the field map mechanism fill in the fields based on the metadata the source entity provides via the media source plugin.

I am fairly certain we could write the necessary two step entity form, but I'd be surprised if it didn't exist already. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there do not seem to be any modules improving the metadata mapping workflow for Media in Drupal core.

There are core issues to improve the metadata mapping and improving the metadata mapping is currently a high priority issue to deliver in Drupal 8.7:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2836153
- https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2862467
- https://www.drupal.org/core/roadmap#media-metadata